# Using DefaultAzureCredential Locally to access Azure Azure Key Vault (using IIS)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault, azure-cli, azure-identity

I've become quite frustrated trying to use Azure KeyVault to store and retrieve my secrets.

My C# code retrieves secrets from the vault and runs on a local IIS website. Here's the code that attempts to read a secret from my Azure vault:

```
var keyVaultURL = configuration["AzureKeyVaultUrl"];
var secretsClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultURL), new DefaultAzureCredential());

var snipcartAPIKey = secretsClient.GetSecret("MyKeyNameHere").Value;
```

When the code tries to call the GetSecret() line, the application crashes with the following error:

> AggregateException: Multiple exceptions were encountered while
> attempting to authenticate. (EnvironmentCredential authentication
> unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.)
> (ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. No Managed
> Identity endpoint found.) (SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication
> unavailable. No accounts were found in the cache.) (Visual Studio
> Token provider file not found at
> C:\Users\AsoRockFood.local\AppData\Local.IdentityService\AzureServiceAuth\tokenprovider.json)
> (Stored credentials not found. Need to authenticate user in VSCode
> Azure Account.) (Please run 'az login' to set up account)

As I understand it, this error message is displaying all the ways the DefaultAzureCredential has attempted to be used. I would expect the Visual Studio token option to work since I can log in to Azure via Visual Studio 2022, but the message does mention that it can't find the tokenprovider.json file. How can I make Visual Studio generate one?

There seems to be a tokenprovider.json file located in another user directory. When I delete it, it gets recreated. However, as you can see from the error message, it's not looking for the token file in that location.

I have checked:

1. I am logged in to Azure in Visual Studio and Azure CLI.
2. I have verified that Tools > Options > Azure Service Authentication has the correct Azure account configured.
3. The account that created the Azure Vault instance in the Azure Portal is the same one that I am using in Visual Studio and Azure CLI - and the account has the correct permissions.
4. I have ensured that setProfileEnvironment is set to True inside my applicationHost.config file, as outlined in this Microsoft post: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/service-to-service-authentication?view=azure-dotnet#cant-retrieve-tokens-when-debugging-app-in-iis)
5. I have the latest updates for Visual Studio 2022 installed, and I also have Azure Development options installed via the Visual Studio Installer.

Comment: What is the .NET Version you are using ?

Comment: @Harshitha .NET 6.0

Comment: Check the below solution,It is for .NET 6 only.

Comment: @Harshitha - I have tried that already... signed in... signed out.. signed in again. Still doesn't work. - I'm so fed up, I'm going to uninstall VS 2022 and install it again. If that fails I am just going to give up with keyvault all together.

Comment: Hope for the best.Try once again.

Comment: @Harshitha You seem to have expreince with this and are recognised by Microsoft on Stack... any change we could do a live share/ screen share... see if you can help me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252847/discussion-between-harshitha-and-ayo-adesina).

Answer (score 1):

> ```cs
> AggregateException: Multiple exceptions were encountered while attempting to authenticate. (EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.) 
> (ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. No Managed Identity endpoint found.) 
> (SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable. No accounts were found in the cache.) 
> (Visual Studio Token provider file not found at C:\Users\AsoRockFood.local\AppData\Local.IdentityService\AzureServiceAuth\tokenprovider.json) (Stored credentials not found. Need to authenticate user in VSCode Azure Account.) (Please run 'az login' to set up account)>
> ```

As mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-dotnet#defaultazurecredential), `DefaultAzureCredential` uses different types of authentication methods.

```cs
Environment
Managed Identity
VisualStudio
Visual Studio Code 
Azure CLI
Azure Powershell
```

You can see the same order of authentication types in the error which you got.

If any of the authentication method is successful, then it stops the process.

- For `Environment`, we need to set the `Azure` - `ClientID`, `Client Secret` and `TenantID`  in the Visual Studio local `Environment Variables`.
- To use `Managed Identity` the Application has to be deployed in Azure App Service.

> I would expect the Visual Studio token option to work since I can log in to Azure via Visual Studio 2022,

- If you want to authenticate with `VisualStudio`, then check the below steps.

In `Visual Studio` => `Tools` => `Options` => Under `Azure Service Authentication` select `Account Selection`.

[image]

Choose the same account for which you have the `Azure Subscription`.

Iam able to retrieve the secret even with your code as well.

***Modify the code as below.***

`appsettings.json`

```cs
 "KeyVault": {
    "URL": "https://KVName.vault.azure.net/"
  }
```

`Program.cs`

```cs
var KVURL = builder.Configuration["KeyVault:URL"];
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(KVURL), credential);

var KVSecret = await secretClient.GetSecretAsync("MySecret");
Console.WriteLine(KVSecret.Value.Value);
```

Make sure your Account has required permissions in the KeyVault.

[image]
***Output:***

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can see you are running a .NET 6 console app, whereas @Ayo Adesina is attempting to access the KeyVault using his local IIS.